# How to solve 'error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct vtkTable’?

Tags: pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download pcl for ros:

```
  svn co http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_electric_unstable
```

And I rosmake,it shows the error:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/e1014fc9c23e6093fce244d3c5f353ef

How to solve it?

Thank you~

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38865/how-to-solve-%27error:-invalid-use-of-incomplete-type-%E2%80%98struct-vtktable%E2%80%99-?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2246 on 2012-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
[ rosmake ] rosdep check failed to find system dependencies: libvtk-qt
```

It look like you need to install libvtk-qt package. In ubuntu, it comest with name libvtk5.x-qt4. You can find it using synaptic

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1